# Running remote command with fabric doesn't separate stdout and stderr streams

Tags: python, fabric

I have a python file like so in my home directory

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('THIS IS STDOUT\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.write('THIS IS STDERR\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
```

When I run this python file, I get output to stdout/stderr as expected.

Now, I have the following fabfile:

```
from fabric.api import run, task

@task
def my_task(cmd):
    run(cmd)
```

When I run the task, both lines get reported as coming from stdout:

```
$ fab --host localhost my_task:'python foo.py'
[localhost] Executing task 'my_task'
[localhost] run: python foo.py
[localhost] out: THIS IS STDOUT
[localhost] out: THIS IS STDERR
[localhost] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
```

Why does fabric pipe stderr into stdout? Looking [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/io.py#L44) stderr lines should get `err:` prepended to them, not `out`. Moreover, adding some debugging statements in there I can see that there is an object set up to watch `stderr`; however it's just not getting any data. Is there a way to change this so that the error lines get `err:` in front of them?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable `combine_stderr`:

```
run(cmd, combine_stderr=False)
```